# Consuming SAP WebService - request sent twice and fails every time

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sap-basis

I'm struggling a bit with consuming a SAP webservice. I've been through many tutorials and also many threads on MSDN, but I cannot find a solution for my problem:

Running my program ends up with this error:

```
CommunicationException not handled.
-> unknown Messageversion

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException wurde nicht behandelt.
HResult=-2146233087
Message=Unbekannte Nachrichtenversion.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: 
   bei   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut.ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE(ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATERequest request)
   bei ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gutClient.ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut.ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE(ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATERequest request) in C:\Users\tstaat\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\ServiceReference2\Reference.cs:Zeile 138.
   bei ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gutClient.ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE(ZTST_USER_PWD[] USER) in C:\Users\tstaat\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\ServiceReference2\Reference.cs:Zeile 144.
   bei ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\tstaat\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:Zeile 61.
   bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

What seems weird to me:

I tested the request created through SoapUI. I had to erase the comments, then it works fine:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE>
         <USER>
            <item>
            <!-- erased comment -->
               <USER>o</USER>
               <PWD>kkkk</PWD>
            </item>
         </USER>
      </urn:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So finally my code looks like this:

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            binding.AllowCookies = true;

            var address = new EndpointAddress("http://host/relativeurn);

            //create client
            ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gutClient client = new ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gutClient(binding, address);

            Console.WriteLine("Created Client");

            //define credentials
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PWD";
            

            ServiceReference2.ZTST_USER_PWD[] parameter = new ServiceReference2.ZTST_USER_PWD[2];
            parameter.Initialize();

            parameter[] = something

            client.open();

            parameter =   client.ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE(parameter);
```

The second error is that the request to the webservice is sent twice: once with and once without authentfication.

I went through this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9f99777-f702-4c0e-8198-b110f8eacdd9/net-c-console-application-calling-sap-webservice?forum=wcf

It doesn't fit exactly for me, cause on

```
 parameter =   client.ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE(parameter);
```

my programme for two requests; the second one is accepted by the server (the first doesn't authenticate), but returns an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsdl:documentation>
            <sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN_BN_ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER">
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" wsp:Optional="true"/>
            <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/soap/features/http-optimization" xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" wsp:Optional="true"/>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
                    <wsp:All>
                        <sp:TransportBinding>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:TransportToken>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:HttpsToken>
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                            <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:HttpsToken>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:TransportToken>
                                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                <sp:Layout>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:Strict/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:Layout>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportBinding>
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
        </wsp:Policy>
        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF_IF_ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut">
            <sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
            <sapsession:enableSession>false</sapsession:enableSession>
            </sapsession:Session>
                <sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration xmlns:sapcentraladmin="http://www.sap.com/webas/700/soap/features/CentralAdministration/" wsp:Optional="true">#
            <sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>3EB6184C46517B16E1000000AC10FEEB</sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>
            </sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration>
        </wsp:Policy>
        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_IF_OP_ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE">
            <sapcomhnd:enableCommit xmlns:sapcomhnd="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/commit/">false</sapcomhnd:enableCommit>
            <sapblock:enableBlocking xmlns:sapblock="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/blocking/">true</sapblock:enableBlocking>
            <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>
            <saprmnw05:enableWSRM xmlns:saprmnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/wsrm/">false</saprmnw05:enableWSRM>
        </wsp:Policy>
        <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
                <xsd:simpleType name="char12">
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:simpleType name="char40">
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="40"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:complexType name="ZTST_USER_PWD">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="USER" type="tns:char12"/>
                        <xsd:element name="PWD" type="tns:char40"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ZTST_USER_PWD_TAB">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:ZTST_USER_PWD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="USER" type="tns:ZTST_USER_PWD_TAB"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATEResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="OUT_TAB" type="tns:ZTST_USER_PWD_TAB"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
        <wsdl:message name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE"/>
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATEResponse">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATEResponse"/>
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:portType name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IF_IF_ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut"/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        <wsdl:operation name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_IF_OP_ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE"/>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATEResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
        <wsdl:binding name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER" type="tns:ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN_BN_ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER"/>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:operation name="ZTST_MASS_USER_CREATE">
                <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
                <wsdl:input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </wsdl:input>
                <wsdl:output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </wsdl:output>
                </wsdl:operation>
        </wsdl:binding>
            <wsdl:service name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER">
                <wsdl:port name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER" binding="tns:ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER">
                    <soap:address location="http://something"/>
                </wsdl:port>
            </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

**update:**

THIS is my appl.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER">
                    <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>          
            <endpoint address="http://somehost/relativeblabla"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER"
                contract="ServiceReference2.ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER_gut" name="ZTST_MASS_CREATE_USER" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me! The errors above will happen if you choose add service Reference instead of Web Service Reference, when you need a WEB SERVICE REFERENCE. For adding a webREferenz to your project:

[image: First Step]

[image: Second Step]

[image: Third Step]