# Add Web Service Reference fails

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, sap-basis

I'm trying to connect a SAP soap provider with a C# program...

@Edit: SAP on it's non-public webservice provider, prompts for user and password (before anything)

Using the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141875/684646):

I came to the webservice I have to attach to, and when user/password prompted, I've placed it. <s>However I think I've written the password wrong</s> (*See **EDIT II** down below*), because the soap response is this one:

```
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
- <soap:Body>
- <soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>No binding data for configuration key: "005056AA63891ED480C5CC2F714805E3"</faultstring> 
- <detail xmlns:slibfault="http://xml.sap.com/2005/11/esi/slib/fault/">
  <slibfault:timestamp>Tue, 15 Jul 2014 16:01:21 GMT</slibfault:timestamp> 
- <slibfault:exception>
  <slibfault:text>No binding data for configuration key: "005056AA63891ED480C5CC2F714805E3"</slibfault:text> 
  <slibfault:position program="CL_SRT_WSP_WSDL_HANDLER=======CP" include="CL_SRT_WSP_WSDL_HANDLER=======CM00K" line="82" /> 
  </slibfault:exception>
  </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Now, User and Password **aren't prompted**, as if a "*Remind My Password*" checkbox were checked.

<s>Is there any way to refresh the "Visual Studio WebService cache" or something?</s>

**@EDIT II**: I've tried twice now *(by adding it to another project with the same results)* and it's not problem that the passwd has been miswritten, the pass is correct, but the reference builder keeps showing this.

> WebServices Found at this URL:
>
> ```
> There was an error downloading 'http://fooserver:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_005056AA63891ED480C5CC2F714805E3/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=400/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
> The request failed with the error message:
> --
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://s
> ```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you send the exact service url you are trying to reference in your project ?

Comment: nope, it's intranet and I have an NDA signed.

Comment: is your soap web service has .asmx at the end or .svc ?

Comment: I've tried both WebService Reference and Service Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this response is the one you receive from SAP, it means **the service exposed has been deprecated**.

I cannot explain *what* is happening from the SAP side, (since I'm a C# dev), but What I do can tell you is that the SAP side is *intentionally* (***manual abap developer handling***) not expecting further communications from clients.

So... ask your ABAPer on your SAP side, he may have done something with the service you where trying to connect to, since it's no longer available.

You can also **verify that** by going to the wsdl page "manually" by placing it in the browser. You'll see the same XML response.

**@Icing-on-the-cake Edit**: If you encounter the issue that credentials is somewhat stored/cached by .Net, simply

- go to the `Solution Panel`,
- left click on the `project` on which you tried to add the reference
- and select `unload project`.

Afterwards repeat that but to `Load` that same project.

That will "*refresh*" the credentials "*stored*".